# Silverlight DataGrid - Hiding a Row while showing its RowDetails

Tags: silverlight

I have a Silverlight DataGrid and want to show the RowDetails of selected rows (RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected").
 
That is no problem. But at the same time I would like to hide the selected row itself. Kind of swapping a row with its details.

Setting the row Visibility to Collapsed or the Height to 0 does not work for me because then the details will also be hidden. Is there a way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

The height of the row is the height of the row itself plus the height if its details. Although you cannot retrieve this height at run time (it is 'NaN'), its possible to set it. As I pointed out in my question, I tried to set it 0, which makes it disappear completely, including the details. But if I just set the height of the row to the height that the details will have according to my style, the display of row with details will be cropped on top and make the row slide 'behind' the row or header above. And that's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Can you please post some xaml too?